# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter

Have some trouble with this exception. I already declare all the data type in model, but it still return this exception. Is it a problem on the backend side?

This is my User model

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  final String password;
  final String nama;
  @JsonKey(name: "nomor_hp")
  final String nomorHp;
  final String email;
  final String aktif;

  User({
    required this.password,
    required this.nama,
    required this.nomorHp,
    required this.email,
    required this.aktif});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data) => _$UserFromJson(data);
  Map<String,dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);

}
```

The result from json_serializable

```
User _$UserFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return User(
    password: json['password'] as String,
    nama: json['nama'] as String,
    nomorHp: json['nomor_hp'] as String,
    email: json['email'] as String,
    aktif: json['aktif'] as String,
  );
}
```

Here is my service

```
  Future<User> getUser(String email, String password) async {
      String _finalUrl = baseUrl + "user/$email/$password";
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(_finalUrl));
      print(response.statusCode);
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
          final data = json.decode(response.body);
          print(data);
          return User.fromJson(data);
      } else {
        throw Exception();
      }
  }
```

Tried to print the data result and this is the output

```
{user: [{id_user: 1, password: test123, nama: Bima Satria, nomor_hp: 08122982900, email: test123@gmail.com, aktif: aktif}]}
```

Here is the JSON response I got from postman

```
{
    "user": [
        {
            "id_user": 1,
            "password": "test123",
            "nama": "Bima Satria",
            "nomor_hp": "08122982900",
            "email": "test123@gmail.com",
            "aktif": "aktif"
        }
    ]
}
```

Maybe I miss something, so please tell me if I miss something in my code. Thank you.

Comment: your response data, `user` is in list format that's why you got error

Comment: @JahidulIslam yeah, thank you, realize it after looking again at the response

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like I miss the the return from JSON response. It should be `return User.fromJson(data['user'][0])` because it returns as an array of object

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote a tiny sample [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=736f0d0d00fcfc2fec3614ab5e4f1d47)

Juest add new class as below

```
@JsonSerializable()
class UsersResult {
  @JsonKey(name: "user")
  final List<User> users;
  
  UsersResult({
    required this.users,
  });
  
  factory UsersResult.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> data) => 
_$UsersResultFromJson(data);
  
  static List<User> _usersFromJson(List<dynamic> jsonList) {
    List<User> objects = [];
    for(Map<String,dynamic> json in jsonList) {
      objects.add(User.fromJson(json));
    }
    return objects;
  }
}

UsersResult _$UsersResultFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return UsersResult(
      users: UsersResult._usersFromJson(json['user']),
  );
}
```